# Access violation writing to static global variable?

Tags: c, string

Given the following code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "string.h"
static char *myStaticArray[] = {"HelloOne", "Two", "Three"};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char * p = strstr(myStaticArray[0],"One");
    char hello[10];
    memset(hello,0,sizeof(hello));
    strncpy(hello,"Hello",6);
    strncpy(p,"Hello",3); // Access Violation
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting an access violation at precisely the point when it attempts to write to the address of myStaticArray[0].
Why is this a problem?

Background: I'm porting old C++ to C# as primarily a C# developer, so please excuse my ignorance! This piece of code apparently wasn't an issue in the old build, so I'm confused...

Comment: This isn't C++. It's basically C, and holds no relation to good C++ code at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
char * p = strstr(myStaticArray[0],"One");
```

`p` points to a part of the string literal "HelloOne". You mustn't try to modify string literals, that's undefined behaviour.

Often, string literals are stored in a read-only part of the memory, so trying to write to them causes a segmentation fault/access violation.

Comment: Simple answer as I suspected, thanks for the quick response. Was something like this ever allowed under a much older compiler?

Comment: @Riken : It may have appeared to work on some older compiler, but it's always been undefined behavior.

Comment: @Riken string literals can be modifiable as a C extension so can be modifiable on some implementations.

Comment: Ooh, as far as I know, it always was undefined behaviour. But I'm no expert on the history. However, undefined behaviour includes the possibility "works as intended (when using a particular compiler)".

Comment: @ouah: That's only allowed because it used to mistakenly allow it, and they want customer's code to keep compiling.  Don't use that extension (or any other that you don't have to).

Comment: @MooingDuck Yes, I added this as a note. Riken: In the Standard, it is noted as a *common extension*, see *(C99, J.5.5p1) Writable string literals*.

Comment: Interesting. I won't be using this code for much longer, just trying to get the project to build and get some historical perspective. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

```
 static char *myStaticArray[] = {"HelloOne", "Two", "Three"};
```

The strings in the array are string literals and are non-modifiable in C and in C++.

```
strncpy(p,"Hello",3);
```

This function call attempts to modify a string literal.

Another issue is your use of the `strncpy` function which does not always null terminate the string. This is the case here because `strlen("Hello")` is greater than `3` (your last `strncpy` argument).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to modify the strings then you'll need to allocate the character arrays like this

```
static char myStaticArray[][25] = {"HelloOne", "two", "three"};
```

The problem, as others stated is that your method causes the compiler create an array of 3 pointers to constant strings.  The above declaration creates a two dementional character array, then copies the constant-string data to that memory.